# What does a colon after function parameters before the brace mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need help to understand this code.

```
getDataSource: function(posts): ListView.DataSource {
return this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(posts);
}
```

This is an anonymous function.  I cannot figure out why they put ": ListView.DataSource" there.  Is this the return value datatype?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: Your code example appears to be almost verbatim from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/Movies/SearchScreen.js#L220

Comment: yes,I copied the code from one of the react native tutorial.  i just try to understand why they put ListView.Datasource after the Anonymous function.  The link you shared doesn't explain that.

Comment: Yes, looks like a non-standard type annotation. JSX, flow or typescript probably.

Comment: @Bergi  thank you so much. this is the answer I am looknig for. please answer the question so i can give you the credit.

Comment: @qinking126: Which of them was it?

Comment: I believe its using flow.